# Need to Reset Google Assistant Default App Preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, google-assistant-sdk

I am looking in Google Assistant for Voice Action. So I started with android.intent.action.SET_ALARM action. When I run the application for the first time and went to Google Assistant- "Okay Google. Set alarm for 10 o clock". For that voice input Google have prompted two apps as follows,

1. Clock Application
2. Set Alarm Sample (My Application with set alarm action)

So, I selected my application and I got time and minute as well in getIntent().

My problem here is, When I say "Okay Google. Set Alarm for 10 o clock" for the next time. It is not showing those two apps like first time. It is directly launching last selected default app.

How to reset this preference?

Answer (score 0):

You can go into the settings for your app. There should be a section for App Defaults. You can clear defaults and you'll get that prompt again.

Comment: I checked this option earlier itself. But, when I see the app defaults section, "Clear default" button was disabled for my application. But still Google Assistant launching My application when I Say set alarm action. I Even restarted my phone also. But Still facing the same issue.   

Is there any preference we need to clear for Google Assistant Voice Actions.?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out the answer on my own.

Long click the Action in Google assistance conversation page say for example "Set alarm for 10 o clock". Just long click this sentence. You could see following options,

1. Edit query
2. Delete Group

Just click "Edit query", it will redirect to next page. There google assistance will displays list of application receives "Set Alarm" Action. From there you can change the application you want to receive Set Alarm action.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way.  After asking Google assistant to set the alarm, I saw options at the bottom of the screen to set an alarm, reminder, etc.  I pressed the option to set alarm.  Then it prompted me with what time to set and showed the clock icon.  I clicked on the icon of the clock it prompted me with selecting which clock to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just say "Set Alarm" without telling the time. It will ask you the time. In that screen, it will show you the app it will be using to set the alarm. Click on that and change it.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I wrongly chose Firefox for query "show me shopping list", which opens up shopping list.google in a browser. The following solution worked for me:

1. Query again the action you'd like to change
2. Scroll up for historical queries to see a tile where the action is mentioned.
3. Historical queries should be visible differently than the most recent one and the action is "detached" in the conversation balloon.
4. Simply tap the action section of the balloon. It will prompt to choose default application and a checkbox to remember the choice should be accessible.

Reset of the OS default setting does not have any impact. There are no default apps settings for different actions in the Google app settings, nor Assistant preferences.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You should probably post this question on Super User instead of Stack Overflow. Also, while posting questions, don't forget to add tags so that people familiar with those tags can help you out.